# Is this sentence grammatically irrefutable?

Tags: grammar

> I am ameliorating my perspicaciousness about Computer Science by diving into its chasmic insight.

Is the above sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: I don't know about irrefutable but it seems quite meaningless.

Comment: Seems like an unusual way to use *ameliorating* and *perspicaciousness*, but that's not a grammar issue. The sentence reads as if *its* refers to your perspicaciousness, and I don't think that's what you intend.

Comment: @nnnnnn What's better?

Comment: @Elliot What's better?

Comment: @Cognoscenti I'd suggest "I'm improving my poor understanding of Computer Science by studying it thoroughly." Unless you're trying to cover something up, that is. The acronym KISS applies (Keep It Simple Safe).

Comment: @Boldben Thanks

Comment: I assume that you wrote a computer program to generate your question. I advise dropping it down a chasm until it is no longer insight.

Comment: @BoldBen Yes, your sentence is a logical improvement to satisfy -Cogniscenti  My suggestions would focus on the chasm reference with several gravity enhancing verbs added. And FYI for you; KISS is classically and properly known as Keep It Simple *Stupid*. No symbolism, intended.

Comment: @Elliot Cognoscenti is a new contributer, I was being kind.

Comment: There is no such thing as being grammatically irrefutable. If the question is whether the sentence is grammatically correct, the answer is that, yes, it is. It is, however, puzzling what is the point of asking whether it is grammatically correct, as it is very easy to construct sentences that are grammatically correct but meaningless.

Comment: @jsw29 I think the phrase "grammatically irrefutable" stands aright, unscathed and impeccable.

Comment: @BoldBen And so you were. I will attempt to stop correcting others when kindness such as yours will suffice.

Comment: @Elliot No problem. Although I didn't invent Keep It Simple Safe, I have seen it as a (perhaps more PC) version of the original.

Comment: @BoldBen Hard to believe but I'll take it. I've become too used to Keep It Simple Dumb A. these past years.

Comment: @Elliot I worked for a British local authority. PC-ness sometimes gets carried to ridiculous extremes in that environment.

Comment: @BoldBen I was looking for an email to connect with you from your bio-page; no luck. I am plagued here by mask-police and virus quackery. Graham Greene said "In a mad world it always seems simpler to obey."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am suppressing my irritation about this question by ignoring its astonishing obscurity.

... which leads me to the conclusion that your sentence is grammatically correct.

Comment: I importune you to indulge in magnanimity and vehemently express your irritation about this question, though, at your leisure.

Comment: I think it should be "...ameliorating my perspicaciousness **of** Computer Science..."? "about" seems informal and grammatically disputable.